# SQL - Need to count empty/null values and add to unknown variable

Tags: sql

Is there a way to include 'UNKNOWN' in the count of this statement. IE there are also varieties as 'UNKNOWN' and some are empty strings. This code would give me two 'UNKNOWN' varieties

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(NULLIF(VARIETY, ''), 'UNKNOWN') AS Variety, 
    COUNT(Variety) AS Total
FROM
    CaneParcel 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT(parcel_id) 
            FROM DeliveryTons 
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT BSI_CODE 
                          FROM FarmerGroups 
                          WHERE ASSN = 'BSCFA-CZ' 
                            AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi 
                            AND remarks = '' 
                            AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = '3' 
                            AND CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = DeliveryTons.parcel_id)) 
GROUP BY
    Variety
ORDER BY
    Variety ASC
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output. Also your query looks strange, does it work apart from the 'UNKNOWN' part? To me it looks like you can use JOIN?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used there.)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant brackets and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT parcel_id ...`!

Comment: `GROUP BY ISNULL(NULLIF(VARIETY, ''), 'UNKNOWN')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group empty strings and UNKNOWN together, then say that in your `GROUP BY` expression:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(NULLIF(VARIETY, ''), 'UNKNOWN') AS Variety, 
    COUNT(Variety) AS Total
FROM
    CaneParcel 
WHERE 
   ...
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(NULLIF(VARIETY, ''), 'UNKNOWN')
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(NULLIF(VARIETY, ''), 'UNKNOWN') ASC
```